# Transformation of matrix - kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ be given by $T(x,y,z) = (y,z)$.
>   Show that $T$ is linear.
>   Prove that the $\ker(T) = \mathrm{Span}(e1)$.

Could you help me?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried?

Comment: I am not sure how can I find the ker(T). I am guessing that it should be sth like this : ker(T) = { (x,y,z) : y=z= 0}.
About the linearity: i should prove that T((x,y,z) + (x1,y1,z2)) = (y+y1, z +z1) or something else?

Comment: You're absolutely right! $$\operatorname{ker}(T)=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:y=z=0\}.$$ Now you must show that this is precisely the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ spanned by $e_1$. As for linearity, you must show that for any $\vec u,\vec v\in\Bbb R^3$ and any real scalar $\lambda,$ you have $$T(\vec u+\vec v)=T(\vec u)+T(\vec v)$$ (which is basically what you said) and that $$T(\lambda\vec u)=\lambda T(\vec u).$$

Answer (score 1):

Do prove linearity, and as for the kernel observe that

$$(x,y,z)\in\ker T\iff T(x,y,z):=(y,z)=(0,0)\iff y=z=0\implies$$

$$\implies \ker T=\text{Span}\,\{(1,0,0)\}$$